# What's the best way to retrieve images from firebase without overloading an app?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage

I have an adapter which retrieves the user profile picture and the post content image like a post on Facebook, but trying to load two different images in a single post is overloading my app and the app becomes slow. How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). In particular pay attention to the [mre] section and that one should avoid phrasing questions to ask for opinion based answers like "best way".

Comment: Are you using Firebase Storage?